# Problem on fixed point existence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If f is a continuous map from closed unit disc to unit circle, then f must have a fixed point. I was trying that problem, by assuming for shake of contradiction, let f does not have any fixed point , then the map (f(x)-x)/||f(x)-x|| is defined, But I can not get any contradiction, how we use that map, or am I in a wrong way ? Please someone help.

Comment: What is your background? Algebraic topology?

Comment: Apply Brouwer fixed-point theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @ Teresa Lisbon , you can say using Algebraic topology. I will be grateful to you.